# Testing React Native FlatList with Enzyme

Tags: javascript, react-native, enzyme, jestjs

I'm trying to test with Enzyme a React Native FlatList. I want to check if the right function is called when the list reaches the end:

```
import { listIsAtTheEnd } from "./actions";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
jest.mock("./actions");


describe("Main page", () => {
    if("Calls listIsAtTheEnd when FlatList reaches the end", () => {
        var app = mount(<App />);
        var container = app.find("FlatListContainer");
        var fList = container.childAt(0);
        fList.instance().scrollToEnd();

        expect(listIsAtTheEnd.mock.calls).toHaveLength(1)
    })
})
```

But this is what I'm getting:

```
TypeError: this._scrollRef.scrollTo is not a function

  at VirtualizedList.scrollToEnd (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js:219:17)
  at FlatList.scrollToEnd (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/FlatList.js:544:141)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/forumPage/__tests__/forumPageTests.js:81:21)
  at tryCallTwo (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
  at doResolve (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
  at new Promise (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
```

What am I doing wrong? What's the correct way to test this?

Answer (score 6):

As it stands it doesn't seem possible/very nice to test React Native with enzyme as soon as you go beyond a very simple shallow render and snapshot combo.

I've found using [Test Renderer](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html) far more reliable to render out something like a `FlatList`, traversing it and invoking actions

In addition testing the above is going to be tricky, so far I've been checking the correct APIs are invoked using spies rather than actually testing the functionality as above.

This error happens though because `scrollTo` hasn't been correctly mocked on the `ScrollView` mock which you can hack around with `jest.mock` for example. See: [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13034)

Comment: Agreed. I tried using `enzyme` with `react-native-mock-render` to help mock the native components but I didn't find the mocked components were complete enough for asserting or snapshotting and ended up reverting to `jest` and `react-test-renderer`. It's a moving target. React Native gains new controls like `FlatList` and they need to be mocked out properly if you're going to do any decent testing on it. Not an easy task.